# Can't open activity, screen flickers after splash screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I am a newbie in Android programming. I have a splash screen after which I am trying to open an activity but after the splash screen my screen keeps flickering and the activity doesn't open. show anything. My code is as follows:

---

**Splashscreen.java**

```
 public class splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity 
{

ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slideinright);
    imageView.setAnimation(animation);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

---

**Loginpage.java**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
 import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
 import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

  public class LoginActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements       View.OnClickListener {

private Button loginbuttonRegister;
private EditText logineditTextEmail;
private EditText logineditTextPassword;
private TextView textViewLogin;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private Profile profile;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);
     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if( firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){

        //display navigation activity
        finish();
        startActivity(new    Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
    }
    loginbuttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbuttonRegister);
    logineditTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logineditTextEmail);
    logineditTextPassword = (EditText)   findViewById(R.id.logineditTextPassword);
    textViewLogin =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);
    loginbuttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginbuttonRegister = (Button)          findViewById(R.id.loginbuttonRegister);
            if(v == loginbuttonRegister)
            {
                userLogin();
            }

        }



    });
    textViewLogin.setOnClickListener(this);




    //Initializing Facebook Sdk.
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    //intialize callback manager
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    //initializing facebook login button

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click

            loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                ProfileTracker profileTracker;
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity2.this,"Succesfully Logged In",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    //check profile is fetched or not, if not then wait for sometime
                    // to load your profile using profile tracker
                    if(profile == null){
                        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                            @Override
                            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile1) {
                                if(profile1 != null){
                                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity2.this,MainActivity.class));
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }else{
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity2.this,MainActivity.class));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                }
            });
        }
    });





   }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}





private void userLogin(){
    String email = logineditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = logineditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //mail empty

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    //if valid then shows progressbar
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loggin in...!");

    progressDialog.show();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {    progressDialog.dismiss();
                //start anvigation activity
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            }

            else {progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity2.this, "Failed to login! Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view == textViewLogin)
    {finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Registeruser.class));
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Loginactivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_login2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.dell.Swing.LoginActivity2"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login2"
android:background="@drawable/probeach">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/registerlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter your E-mail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:id="@+id/logineditTextEmail"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter your Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/logineditTextPassword" />

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginbuttonRegister"
        android:text="Log In"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:elevation="0dp" />


    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Not Registered? Sign up Here"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLogin" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orview"
        android:text="Or"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.63"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/orview"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want to show log in screen after splash? if yes then please check you animation end call back. You are passing MainActivity (I am supposing this is not your log in screen) into explicit intent.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed my launcher activity is splashscreen ,then i want it to show my login page but when i comment that  total firebase code  in loginactivity ,i get the page but i cant use my signup,i can only use my facebook login.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your background image resolution,

```
android:background="@drawable/probeach"
```

Comment: i dont think its affecting ,cause when i comment my firebase code it shows the loginactivity page